# Making specific words or bunch of words bold in phppresentation

Tags: php, phppresentation

How to make particular words or lines bold in paragraph using phppresentation.

```
$textRun = $shape->createTextRun('Your content is centered around promotion of events. While we encourage continuing this practice based on the strong results.');
      $textRun->getFont()->setSize(13);
      $textRun->getFont()->setColor($colorBlack);
      $textRun->getFont()->setName('Montserrat');
```

In above text I want to make 'promotion of events' to bold and other text as it is. How I can do that in phppresentation library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must divide your text in multiple parts.

You could use this code :

```
$oFont = new Font();
$oFont->setSize(13);
$oFont->setColor($colorBlack);
$oFont->setName('Montserrat');

$oFontBold = clone $oFont;
$oFontBold->setBold(true);

$textRun = $shape->createTextRun('Your content is centered around ');
$textRun->setFont($oFont);

$textRun = $shape->createTextRun('promotion of events');
$textRun->setFont($oFontBold);

$textRun = $shape->createTextRun('. While we encourage continuing this practice based on the strong results.');
$textRun->setFont($oFont);
```

Comment: Thanks @Progi Can you please look  at issue I added on https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/issues/519